# Communication between C++ and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c++

I need help on implementing an interprocess communication mechanism between JavaScript and C++ code. Basically I need to make a bidirectional communication. So JavaScript should be able to send and receive message from C++ (Win 32) code and vice versa.

Comment: You will need to give some more info on what you want to do.  How is the js to be executed in a browser, shell script, embedded interpreter?  Are they on teh same machine, same network?  Does it need to handle firewalls?

Answer (score 2):

You should look at [Google's V8 JavaScript runtime](http://code.google.com/p/v8/), which powers their Chrome browser, it is implemented in C++.  [JSON libraries](http://www.json.org/) will simplify de/serialization.

Answer (score 1):

Qt contains the [QtScript](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtscript.html) module, which is a native C++ implementation of JavaScript. I've used this successfully to script a C++ application, with communication in both directions.

If you're curious, the code is part of my [HP 15C simulator project](https://github.com/ghewgill/hp15c).

Answer (score 1):

If you have the option of using Qt, I strongly recommend it. It's comprehensive and well tested. [QtScript module](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtscript.html). QtScript is a superset of javascript. The implementation uses Webkit's javascript core.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are doing this on a Windows OS. Does any kind of IPC help or are you specific on anything? Try named pipes; or shared memory with a sync object; or try a common file system memory, such as a binary file with a sync object to access it (although this is not recommended but is sure an option).
You may also create COM objects / ActiveX controls and access this from JavaScript (browser).